# Lock user to single directory

Tags: permissions, chroot, vsftpd, restricted-access

I don't want to lock ssh users, I want to lock users in general. If a process is running as a user e.g. `su -c "ls" user1` I want user1 to only ever see the folder `/path/to/folder` and it's subfolders/files and nothing else. No ls to anywhere else. No cd. Nothing.

I have seen many guides but everything is for a user ssh-ing into the machine. I just want a local user that I make to be locked down and unable to see or touch anything but a single folder I allow it to.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: if `user1` can only see `/path/to/folder` how can it execute `ls` then?

Comment: Will this user have a home directory?

Comment: Not sure about your use case, but you might want to use containerization, e.g. `docker`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent access to a folder by other users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200911/how-to-prevent-access-to-a-folder-by-other-users)

Comment: @RoVo, yeah that won't be a good idea, lol.

Comment: @RoVo this is an example but following this /path/to/folder could have many subfolders and files, of which you can `ls`. From the node /path/to/folder and down only.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this method I just tested that prevents access to any other folder but only to the one given ownership to that user.

Steps:

1. Create user without `home` directory:

   ```
   sudo adduser --no-create-home koko
   ```
2. Then create the folders for user `koko`:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /koko/k1/k2
   ```
3. Give access to user `koko` for the folder `k2`

   ```
   sudo chown koko:koko /koko/k1/k2
   ```
4. Remove permission `others` from current home folders in `/home` so `koko` can't access those files or folders

   ```
   sudo chmod 750 /home/folders
   ```

Now koko switch to usaer `koko` and try to access any other fodler, you will get a `permission denied error`, but user `koko` can change into the created `/koko/k1/k2` folders.

Comment: This is *"restricting access to **other home folders**"*, but OP is asking for *"restricting access to **everything but 1 directory**"*.

Comment: @cardin, You are right, I have updated the answer so the user can only access the `k2` folder!